# Directory listing using PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php

function directory_listing($directory_name)
{
    if ($handle = opendir($directory_name)) 
    {
        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) 
        {
            if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") 
            {
                if(is_dir($entry))
                {   

                    **//program is avoiding this block
                    echo $entry.'--<br/>';** 

                }
                else
                {
                    echo $entry.'<br/>';
                }   
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
}


directory_listing('go');

?>
```

I would like to have a directory listing with the above code. But the program is avoiding the mentioned **if block**.

Thanks

Foysal

Comment: `$listing = scandir("go");` works perfectly

Answer (score 5):

To list directories you can use [DirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php)

```
$iterator = new DirectoryIterator('pathtoyourdir/');
foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isDir()) {
        echo $fileinfo->getFilename() . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. the SPL iterators are so powerful... it's sad that so many people are still using old PHP methods for these kinds of things.

Comment: Because they find it in the old tutorials that is why they use old methods instead of using modern ones.

Answer (score 1):

write instead the full relative path:

```
if(is_dir("$directory_name/$entry"))
```

as the `$entry` is not in the current working directory, but in the directory you're reading through.

Answer (score 1):

`$entry` is not the full path to the file/directory. Use `$directory_name.'/'.$entry` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can look at http://php.net/glob

```
foreach (glob('dir/*') as $file) {
    if (is_dir($file)) {
        echo $entry . '--<br />';
    }
    else {
        echo $entry . '<br />';
    }
}
```